# Freemarker: comparing against a default value

Tags: comparison, freemarker, default-value

I have this condition:

```
<#if tag.level?? && tag.level == "IMPORTANT">
```

Is it possible to shorten it to something like this?

```
<#if tag.level!"" == "IMPORTANT">
```

If I try this

```
<#assign tag = {"bar": "AA"} >
${ ((tag.bar)!"x") = "x" }
```

I get

> Can't convert boolean to string automatically, because the "boolean_format" setting was "true,false", which is the legacy default computer-language format, and hence isn't accepted.

See http://freemarker-online.kenshoo.com/

Answer (score 0):

1) `${ ((tag.bar)!"x") = "x" }` should be probably `${ ((tag.bar)!"x") == "x" }`.

2) Use a built-in to display boolean, either `${ (((tag.bar)!"x") = "x")?c }` (if your Freemarker is newer than 2.3.20), or `${ (((tag.bar)!"x") = "x")?string("true", "false") }`

Answer (score 0):

It's a precedence issue that you run into. This works:

```
<#if (tag.level!"") == "IMPORTANT">
```

but for this kind of default there's a shorter form:

```
<#if tag.level! == "IMPORTANT">
```